# three.js loader HTTP2 Protocol Error when cache disabled from Azure CDN

Tags: azure, three.js, azure-storage, http2, azure-cdn

I'm using Three.js loader to load some image assets from Azure storage through Azure CDN
When the browser uses the cache, it works fine, but if the cache has expired, or if I disable the browser cache in dev tools, the loading fails with the error:

net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that experiences this, I fixed it by deleting the CDN resource and re-creating it on the Standard Microsoft plan (it was standard Akamai before).
Not sure if it was the plan change, or simply re-building the CDN that fixed it but it works now